# network scanner installation

Tags: networking, printing, scanner

I have Canon IR 2200 network multi functional device (MFD). I have installed printer but not able to scan. canon provide network scangear utility for windows. I have also installed this utility with wine but still I am able to scan with the help of third party sofware i.e faststone image viewer. I was using faststone image viewer on windows for network scanning. our network MFD IP is 192.168.1.250 & my ubuntu desktop IP is 192.168.1.19. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You've to install XSane pacages for use your scanner device

```
sudo apt-get install xsane
```

or the gnome pacage for scanner:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-scan
```